# How can I extend my viewport in openGL to keep printed text clipped properly?

Tags: opengl, text, printing, glut, coordinate-systems

I am using this code to draw a text in openGL with GLUT:

Code (init part) which sets my origin (0,0) into top-left corner and maintains proper screen-resolution based coordination system :

```
    glViewport(0, 0, x, y);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, x, y, 0, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Code (printing part) :

```
void drawtext(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, const char* string )
{
    glRasterPos2f(x,y);
    while ( *string != '\0' )
         glutBitmapCharacter(p_glutfont,static_cast<int>(*string++));
}
```

And everything would be perfect if not only the fact that when X and Y starts at negative  coordinations (due to the fact that objects with text printed as a tag are partially outside of the view, then the whole text is not being drawn. lets imagine that I have a object with text tag on top of it and it enters the view from left top corner at x = -40, y = 40 :

```
         X axis      window
 axis Y  ----------------------------
        | y=40                       |
 x=-40__|_________                   |
    |Text to print|                  |
    |_____________|                  |
        |                            |
        |                            |
        |____________________________|
```

The text is not being printed until is drawn from exactly X => 0  coordination. Also this problem doesn't exist when text has to be clipped on RIGHT side - then it is printed properly - this is where I I realized that it has to do with initial position of the text.

My question is - how can I EXTEND properly my viewport / screen mapping to :

1) preserve screen coordinations from top-left corner (0,0) to bottom-right (height,width) 2) with internally extended those values just during the printing the text - so the text would get clipped instead of disappearing ?

Although I did my research, I couldn't for 2 days now come to any solution. I tried to play with glViewport and glOrtho but none of changes and approaches I tried (like for example setting glViewport to -x,-y,x*2,y*2) would do the trick - those always mess with my screen coordination system which is essential to keep at window-resolution based.

PS: I did further research and I came across this article http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/clipping.htm.

**10.070 How do I draw glBitmap() or glDrawPixels() primitives that have an initial glRasterPos() outside the window's left or bottom edge?**

> When the raster position is set outside the window, it's often outside
>   the view  volume and subsequently marked as invalid. Rendering the
>   glBitmap and glDrawPixels primitives won't occur with an invalid
>   raster position. Because glBitmap/glDrawPixels produce pixels up and
>   to the right of the raster position, it appears impossible to  render
>   this type of primitive clipped by the left and/or bottom edges of the
>   window.
>
> **However, here's an often-used trick: Set the raster position to a valid value inside the view volume. Then make the following call:**

```
 glBitmap (0, 0, 0, 0, xMove, yMove, NULL);
```

> This tells OpenGL to render a no-op bitmap, but move the current
>   raster position by (xMove,yMove). Your application will supply
>   (xMove,yMove) values that place the raster position outside the view
>   volume. Follow this call with the glBitmap() or glDrawPixels() to do
>   the rendering you desire.

Sadly - I  can't put this advice in work - and once I use it - the text is completely missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is where I I realized that it has to do with initial position of the text.

Almost. glRasterPos is a raster drawing operation command and whatever position you put into it goes through the transformation pipeline. If the point falls outside the clip volume (not the viewport!) it gets discarded and all further raster drawing operations are disabled until a new glRasterPos specified that is not clipped.

The easy and recommended solution would be not to use raster drawing operations at all, because they're slow, poorly supported and have been removed from later OpenGL alltogether. glutBitmapCharacter is using raster drawing ops.

Use texture mapped fonts or stroked characters instead. Google finds uncountable amounts of information on these.

Comment: That's are all valid points - I have come to this realization that I might need to use different printing capabilities in the future projects - but for the purpose I have right now it's quite sufficient so I wouldn't go for entirely new drawing text method IF this is possible to map this clipping view somehow different - which essentially was my question about.

Comment: Also - as described here : http://www.mesa3d.org/brianp/sig97/gotchas.htm - this problem with drawing text in glut is commonly known - and one of solution they suggest is to map coordination system differently. Sadly - I don't get their example at all :(

Comment: @seeoneself: You can not get around the raster operations being disabled if the glRasterPos is transformed outside the clip volume. It's an intrinsic property of OpenGL. If you want to stick with glutBitmapCharacter, then your best bet would probably be to render the text into an intermediate FBO and then draw this into your scene using a textured quad.

Comment: How about that workaround I found on OpenGL.org look up my question - I added PS to it with explanation - basically using glBitmap(0,0,0,desired_X_outside_clip_volume,desired_Y_outside_clip_volume,NULL); which supposed to move rasterpos into desired position - but can't make it works..

Comment: @seeoneself: The idea is the following: The viewport set with glViewport does define the extents of the clip volume boundaries in window coordinates. By defining viewport extents the go beyond the window area you're effectively moving the clip boundaries outside of the window. However this extension of the viewport must be complemented with an adjustment of the projection so that things match again. In the case your projection is an ortho projection doubling the viewport, just pass the viewport extents into the glOrtho left,right,bottom,top parameters.

Comment: @seeoneself: The other trick mentioned is to place the glRasterPos within the clip volume boundaries and draw a null bitmap with glBitmap with a negative value for xmove, to move the text outside the viewport.

Comment: yes I did understood those 1st method - with glOrtho and glViewport I simple can't get right and the other trick with glBitmap simple doesnt work for glutBitmapCharacter. Perhaps I can't make my world coords lets say (-800,-600 to 1600,1200) - and view coords (which would define only visible area) as lets say : 0,0 to 800,600 ?